# ReactiveUI and UWP – Where do these warnings/errors on binding come from?

Tags: uwp, reactiveui

I am trying to create my first ReactiveUI appliation in UWP and have come up against some unexpected warnings/errors that I don’t know what to do with.

I’m using ReactiveUI version 12.1.1 in a UWP (min ver 10/1809/17763, max ver 10/2004/19041) application.

I’ve been following (as much as I think I have done correctly) the instructions here: https://www.reactiveui.net/docs/handbook/data-binding/microsoft-store

Here’s the Page definition:

```
<Page
    x:Class="UwpReactiveUiTest.Views.GridsView"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:local="using:UwpReactiveUiTest.Views"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid>
        <Slider
            x:Name="slider"
            Maximum="50"
            Minimum="0"
            Value="25" />
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Here’s the code behind for the Page:

```
public sealed partial class GridsView : Page, IViewFor<GridsViewModel>
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ViewModelProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
        nameof(ViewModel),
        typeof(GridsViewModel),
        typeof(GridsView),
        new PropertyMetadata(null)
        );

    public GridsViewModel ViewModel
    {
        get => (GridsViewModel)GetValue(ViewModelProperty);
        set => SetValue(ViewModelProperty, value);
    }

    object IViewFor.ViewModel
    {
       get => ViewModel;
       set => ViewModel = (GridsViewModel)value;
    }

    public GridsView()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
 
        ViewModel = new GridsViewModel();
    }
}
```

Here’s the View Model:

```
public class GridsViewModel : ReactiveObject
{
    private double _sliderValue;
    public double SliderValue
    {
        get => _sliderValue;
        set => this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _sliderValue, value);
    }

    public GridsViewModel()
    {
 
    }
}
```

When I run the application every is fine; I get lots of ‘Loading DLL’ messages in the Output, as expected, but that’s all.

However, as soon as I add a binding into the View constructor, such as:

```
public GridsView()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
 
    ViewModel = new GridsViewModel();

    this.WhenActivated(disposableRegistration =>
    {
        this.Bind(ViewModel,
        viewModel => viewModel.SliderValue,
        view => view.slider.Value)
        .DisposeWith(disposableRegistration);
    });
}
```

I get this in the output:

```
Exception thrown: 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
LogHost: Initializing to normal mode
POCOObservableForProperty: The class UwpReactiveUiTest.Views.GridsView property slider is a POCO type and won't send change notifications, WhenAny will only return a single value!
```

My questions are:

1. **Exceptions.**
   Where do the exceptions come from and what can/should I do about it?
2. **POCO Warning.**
   Why do I get a POCO warning and what can/should I do about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Exceptions, if they only happen on startup have been solved [ReactiveUI 2395](https://github.com/reactiveui/ReactiveUI/issues/2395)

2. POCO Warning, this is a warning letting you know that your property won't notify changes.  They can be ignored.  But, if you are wondering why your property won't update, those warnings will usually be the indicator as to why.  I don't know that you can turn it off, but it isn't something to be concerned about.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up for me. I was worried that I had done something silly but, from what you have said, it seems not. At least I can be reasonably sure that they are not affecting the other problems I am getting (NullReferenceException when binding to an ObservableAsPropertyHelper property). I’ll need to look at those in a different way. Your help is much appreciated. Thanks again.